# Comparing two columns data AND returning blanks if input is blank

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of equipment in one column that I own. I have a second list of company equipment that I need to compare what my equipment was used on. I have found a formula to compare the two columns and return "TRUE" if my equipment matches the company equipment and "FALSE" if my equipment was not used.

The problem I have is in the company equipment, there are a lot of blank cells. Those blank cells are giving me a "FALSE" output, when I would rather it give me a blank output as well.

Here is the formula I used to get where I am currently: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D19,$F$6:$F$19,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)

D19 would be the company equipment I am looking to see if it exists in my equipment. My equipment is contained in cells F6:F19.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
= IF( ISBLANK(D19), "", NOT( ISERROR( MATCH( D19, $F$6:$F$19, 0) ) ) )
```

It checks if `D19` is `blank` if so returns `blank`
then if `D19` <> blank checks if `D19` is present in `$F$6:$F$19` and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

No point of using `VLOOKUP` as you don't need any return from `$F$6:$F$19`, just checking if `D19` is there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be wrapping it in another IF where you check if the cell is empty:
`=IF(ISBLANK(D19),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D19,$F$6:$F$19,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE))`

Also, you could replace your outer IF with NOT, shortening the formula a bit:
`=IF(ISBLANK(D19),"",NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D19,$F$6:$F$19,1,FALSE))))`

Comment: It seems that you need to change the place of the `""` in the formulas.

Comment: Right, thanks. I really shouldn't edit the formulas in the comment field.